# Autoshrink Navigation Bar Title iOS 7 or Later

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering what is the best approach to make the UINavigationBar title auto shrink into minimum font size when it is too long?

Below are my example of the problem

**Normal**

[image]

**Too Long (need to shrink the label)**

[image]

And here is the codes I am using to do styling for UINavigationBar

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]]
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName   : [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                       NSFontAttributeName              : [fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0]}];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
```

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14962409/22147

Answer (score 3):

The most common solution is to use a custom view for the title. But you can't do this using UIAppearance, you will need to do this on each UIViewController that you push, or make a category of the UINavigationBar, and add this logic every time the title text is changed (Not sure if this will work or if it's a good idea, though) or create a new adhoc method.

For example (Put this in the viewDidLoad of your UIViewController):

```
UILabel* titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 40)];
titleLabel.text = @"Your very long title";
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; // As alternative you can also make it multi-line. 
titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;     
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```