# manually setting titleView of navigationItem is not alligned vertically

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am using this func inside a `UIViewController` extension to add a title that adjusts font to fit width.

```
extesion UIViewController {
    func setTitleDifferentSizes(title: String){
        self.title = title
        guard let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height else{
            return
        }

        let tlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 
        200.0, height: navigationBarHeight))
        tlabel.text = self.title
        tlabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        tlabel.font = font24
        tlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.navigationItem.titleView = tlabel
    }
}
```

I took this solution from this SO question and changed it a little bit:
[How to resize Title in a navigation bar dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956561/how-to-resize-title-in-a-navigation-bar-dynamically)

Now the issue I have is that the text of the title is not aligned vertically to the other navigation bar items, as you can see in the images, I show one where I just setup the title without using the above method, and the text there cannot fit but it is aligned properly, and the other image is using the method above where the text fits but it is not aligned.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:-

```
   func setTitleDifferentSizes(title: String){
    self.title = title
    guard let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat =
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height else{
            return
    }
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title)

     let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white ,NSFontAttributeName: font24]

    attributedString.addAttributes(myAttribute, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.characters.count))

    attributedString.addAttributes([NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:6.0], range:         NSRange(location: 0, length: title.characters.count)
    )

    let tlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:
        200.0, height: navigationBarHeight))
    tlabel.attributedText = attributedString
    tlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    tlabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
    tlabel.textAlignment = .center
    self.navigationItem.titleView = tlabel
}
```

if you want to adjust the position of text please change the float value of NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName to set the vertical alignment.