# Dynamically resize navigation bar title during Large Titles mode

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, navigationbar

How do I dynamically resize my navigation bar title while in iOS 11's Large Title mode?

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956561/how-to-resize-title-in-a-navigation-bar-dynamically) you could define your own UILabel as the titleView and have it resize. All it does now is add another titleView on top.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "A very long title. Really long. Dont truncate me though. I want everyone to see me."
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
    let tlabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
    tlabel.text = self.title
    tlabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    tlabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17) 
    tlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    tlabel.textAlignment = .center
    self.navigationItem.titleView = tlabel

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62043519/11774595