# Can't set titleView in the center of navigation bar because back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm using an image view to display an image in my nav bar. The problem is that I can't set it to the center correctly because of the back button. I checked the related questions and had almost the same problem earlier that I solved, but this time I have no idea.

Earlier I solved this problem with fake bar buttons, so I tried to add a fake bar button to the right (and left) side, but it doesn't helped.

```
- (void) searchButtonNavBar {


    CGRect imageSizeDummy = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25,25);

    UIButton *dummy = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:imageSizeDummy];

    UIBarButtonItem
    *searchBarButtonDummy =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:dummy];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonDummy;

}


- (void)setNavBarLogo {

    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    CGRect myImageS = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
    UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageS];
    [logo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"color.png"]];
    logo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = logo;
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 0.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

I think it should be workin fine because in this case the `titleView` has bar buttons on the same side. Is there any explanation why it worked with bar buttons that was created programmatically but doesn't works with the common back button?

Comment: Check color.png,its size should be 88*88.

Comment: Can you please add your navigation bar screenshot that you want final output..

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`UINavigationBar` automatically centers its `titleView` as long as there is enough room.  If the title isn't centered that means that the title view is too wide to be centered, and if you set the backgroundColor if your `UIImageView` you'll see that's exactly what is happening.

The title view is too wide because that navigation bar will automatically resize the title to hold its content, using `-sizeThatFits:`.  This means that your title view will always be resized to the size of your image.

Two possible fixes:

1. The image you're using is way too big.  Use a properly sized 44x44 pt image with 2x and 3x versions.
2. Wrap UIImageView inside of a regular UIView to avoid resizing.

Example:

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpeg"]];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

UIView* titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
imageView.frame = titleView.bounds;
[titleView addSubview:imageView];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

Comment: Wrapping the `UIImageView` inside of a regular `UIView` and setting its frame equal to the `UIView`'s bounds is what fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 20):

An example in **Swift 3** version of Darren's second way:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test"))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    imageView.frame = titleView.bounds
    titleView.addSubview(imageView)

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Answer (score 7):

I  suggest you  Override the  function  - (void)setFrame:(CGRect)fram
like this:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame  { 

    [super setFrame:frame]; //systom function

    self.center = CGPointMake(self.superview.center.x, self.center.y);   //rewrite function 

}
```

so  that the titleView.center always the  right location

Answer (score 5):

Don't use titleView.

Just add your image to navigationController.navigationBar

```
CGRect myImageS = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageS];
[logo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"color.png"]];
logo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
logo.center = CGPointMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.width / 2.0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.height / 2.0);
logo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:logo];
```

Comment: Then if you go back in the same navigationcontroller the view is on every controller.

Answer (score 5):

Qun Li's worked perfectly for me. Here's the swift 2.3 code:

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    set(newValue) {
        super.frame = newValue

        if let superview = self.superview {
            self.center = CGPoint(x: superview.center.x, y: self.center.y)
        }
    }

    get {
        return super.frame
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a custom view from a nib, be sure to disable auto-layout on the nib file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out man. I was scratching my head off.

Comment: If you are using Autolayout, it must be turned on on the nib as well.

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom `UINavigationController` that after dropping in, the only thing you have to do is call `showNavBarTitle(title:font:)` when you want to show and `removeNavBarTitle()` when you want to hide:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    private static var mTitleFont = UIFont(name: <your desired font (String)> , size: <your desired font size -- however, font size will automatically adjust so the text fits in the label>)!
    private static var mNavBarLabel: UILabel = {

        let x: CGFloat = 60
        let y: CGFloat = 7
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 2 * x, height: 44 - 2 * y))

        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        label.font = NavigationController.mTitleFont
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center

        return label
    }()

    func showNavBarLabel(title: String, font: UIFont = mTitleFont) {
        NavigationController.mNavBarLabel.text = title
        NavigationController.mNavBarLabel.font = font
        navigationBar.addSubview(NavigationController.mNavBarLabel)
    }

    func removeNavBarLabel() {
        NavigationController.mNavBarLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

I find the best place to call `showNavBarTitle(title:font:)` and `removeNavBarTitle()` are in the view controller's `viewWillAppear()` and `viewWillDisappear()` methods, respectively:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    func viewWillAppear() {
        (navigationController as! NavigationController).showNavBarLabel(title: "Your Title")
    }

    func viewWillDisappear() {
        (navigationController as! NavigationController).removeNavBarLabel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can try setting your image as UINavigationBar's background image by calling

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"color.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

inside the `viewDidLoad` method.

That way it will be always centered, but if you have `back` button with long title as left navigation item, it can appear on top of your logo. And you should probably at first create another image with the same size as the navigation bar, then draw your image at its center, and after that set it as the background image.

2) Or instead of setting your image view as `titleView`, you can try simply adding at as a subview, so it won't have the constraints related to right and left bar button items.

Comment: If I use the first solution my nav bar disappears.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, this is what worked for me however it´s not the best solution (basically, add it up to navigationBar):

```
    let titleIV = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"some"))
        titleIV.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        titleIV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      if let navigationController = self.navigationController{
            navigationController.navigationBar.addSubview(titleIV)
            titleIV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  
navigationController.navigationBar.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            titleIV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationController.navigationBar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
      }
      else{
            view.addSubview(titleIV)
            titleIV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height).isActive = true
            titleIV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Darren's answer, a fix for me was to return a `sizeThatFits` with the `UILabel` size. It turns out that this is called after layoutSubViews so the label has a size.

```swift
override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: titleLabel.frame.width + titleInset*2, height: titleLabel.frame.height)
}
```

Also note that I have `+ titleInset*2` because Im setting the horizontal constraints like so:

```swift
titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: titleInset),
titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -titleInset)
```