# How to insert UISearchBar under NavigationBar Title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Can anyone help me with this?

I am looking to place a searchBar inside of a navigationBar, but under the Title (reason for doing so is that I would like one image for the NavigationBar & SearchBar) Having issues with the <= 1px shadow from NavigationBar. I have accomplished putting the searchBar inside the NavigationItem "Title" but I want it to be below it. Here is what I'm using to put the searchBar inside the NavBar:

```
func createSearchBar()
{
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchBar.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom view to your navigation bar an center that view.

Maybe this can help you:

[Can't set titleView in the center of navigation bar because back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121388/cant-set-titleview-in-the-center-of-navigation-bar-because-back-button)

Or creating a custom nav bar:

https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/11/11/ios-app-creating-custom-nav-bar/

Comment: Did it help you @david ?