# Navigation title UIImageView can't center

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I have a `UIViewController` where I load a picture from internet and I want to display it as the navigation titleView.

Here is my code when I have finished fetching the picture from internet

**Code Snippet :**

```
let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)
imgView.image = result.image!  //Contains the picture from internet
imgView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
self.navigationItem.titleView = imgView
```

**And here is the result:**

[image: titleView not centered]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121388/cant-set-titleview-in-the-center-of-navigation-bar-because-back-button

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out the reason.

So the UIImageView is indeed centered in the titleView.
The problem is that the titleView is not centered because in my case the left bar button item was bigger than the right bar button item.

I had to set both bar button items at the same width and now my titleView is centered.

[image: titleView centered]