# iOS Navgation bar title not in center?

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar

I am not using any customized bar button items in nav bar, just default title and back button in navigation bar. But in one of my view controller the back button is taking up too much space as highlighted in the image. So it's pushing the Nav Title towards right.

I am not sure what is causing this. Is there anyway to adjust the content inset or width of the back button in ios?

[image]

Comment: Does  this VC have any title of previous VC that you might have hidden ??

Comment: Bro, I think you have to look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121388/cant-set-titleview-in-the-center-of-navigation-bar-because-back-button)

Comment: @Mukesh Yeah I have looked into that, but I have not used any custom view as title view. So may not apply in my case.

Comment: @VishalSonawane what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean when we push any VC the pushed VC gets back button along with the title of previous VC. So in your case there is no title for previous VC. have you hidden it ?

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha friend add this code `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];` in previous ViewController while pushing to nextviewcontroller

Comment: No there is a title in previous VC as well.

Comment: Just add that code & let me know.

Comment: Hey @Mukesh Thanx a ton man it worked. What's the logic behind it? If you put it as a answer I will accept and up :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you using default Back Button on Navigation bar,add my working code to previous viewController while pushing to nextViewController

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

And then add title to navigation bar on nextViewController `viewDidLoad:` method

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Restaurants", nil)];
```

Handle back button action event from nextViewController like this,

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"G_Back", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(actionToBackBtnFromDetail:)];
```