# swift - Can't find the numberOfLines attribute of UINavigationBar title text

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have used `UINavigationBar.appearance()` in swift. By using this, I have changed the `backgroundColor` and the `textColor` of `UINavigationBar`using the below code.

However, I can't find the `numberOfLines`attribute of the `UINavigationBar` title text. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
 var naviAppreance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
 naviAppreance.tintColor = uicolorFromHex(0xffffff)
 naviAppreance.barTintColor = uicolorFromHex(0x00cc66)
 naviAppreance.titleTextAttributes = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: Will this post help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422383/uinavigationbar-multi-line-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to design a custom view with a label and assign it as the `titleView` of your `UINavigationBar`

Example Swift Code:

```
var titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 44))
titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
titleLabel.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter
titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12.0) 
titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
titleLabel.text = "This is a\nmultiline string"
self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

Comment: Thanks. but what I want is that  a box size of label is changing dynamically as contents length of label. ( It means that  the number of lines of label must be changed automatically as changing of contents length.

Comment: Try to use titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize().width and modify the  numberOfLines as 0 (titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0). Or just do a google search to find answer for this question https://www.google.co.in/#q=ios+UIlabel+dynamically+contents+length