# How to add Three Labels to Navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am working in a project in which i need to add Three Labels one below the above to the center of the navigation bar, Can anyone help ?

I have tried this snippet:

```
UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 66)];

UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,8,200,30)];
navLabel.text = @"My Text";
navLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[naviBarObj addSubview:navLabel];
[navLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:naviBarObj];
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422383/uinavigationbar-multi-line-title

Comment: you want a multi line text or multiple labels

Comment: yes anbu, I nedd to add three labels one below the another

Comment: Take a custom view and set the frame of the three labels. Then add the custom view like this self.navigationItem.titleView = customView; and it also add in the centre of the navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 110)];

UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,8,200,30)];
navLabel.text = @"My Text";
navLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[navLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

UILabel *navLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,navLabel.frame.origin.y + navLabel.frame.size.height + 5,200,30)];
navLabel1.text = @"My Text1";
navLabel1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[navLabel1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

UILabel *navLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,navLabel1.frame.origin.y + navLabel1.frame.size.height + 5,200,30)];
navLabel2.text = @"My Text2";
navLabel2.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[navLabel2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


[naviBarObj addSubview:navLabel];
[naviBarObj addSubview:navLabel1];
[naviBarObj addSubview:navLabel2];

[self.view addSubview:naviBarObj];
```

Comment: or follow the sailendra answer

Comment: paaka,  tanks anbu(valthukal)

Comment: @Arun - now you got idea , customize urself

Comment: can we use frames while enabling autolayout.

Comment: @Arun - if you are using autolayout - use leading constarints

Comment: @FahimParkar - Ya correct, I asked to questioner bro, he needs three labels, thats the reason I added three labels , else \n or number of lines = 3 or 0 is enough

Comment: just saw that comment... :)

Comment: @Anbu Karthick is there any way to contact u bro.

Comment: @Arun - 8754 846 846

Answer (score 1):

@Arun I have just modify the  Anbu.Karthik code which might help you

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 64.0f)];

UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,2,200,18)];
navLabel.text = @"My Text";
navLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[navLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
navLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[customView addSubview:navLabel];

UILabel *navLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,navLabel.frame.size.height + 2,200,18)];
navLabel1.text = @"My Text1";
navLabel1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
navLabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[navLabel1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[customView addSubview:navLabel1];

UILabel *navLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,navLabel.frame.size.height + navLabel1.frame.size.height + 2,200,18)];
navLabel2.text = @"My Text2";
navLabel2.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
navLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[navLabel2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[customView addSubview:navLabel2];

self.navigationItem.titleView = customView;
```

Output:

[image]

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

if u need to add to your pre defined navigationController then

```
 UILabel *tempLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[tempLabel1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 12)];
[tempLabel1 setText:@"Text 1"];
[tempLabel1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[tempLabel1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:tempLabel1];

UILabel *tempLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[tempLabel2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 12, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 24)];
[tempLabel2 setText:@"Text 2"];
[tempLabel2 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[tempLabel2 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:tempLabel2];

UILabel *tempLabel3 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[tempLabel3 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[tempLabel3 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 24, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 36)];
[tempLabel3 setText:@"Text 3"];
[tempLabel3 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:tempLabel3];
```

change the size of label according to your navigationController

[image]

Comment: but getting this format throught the entire viewcontroller i need it in one viewcontroller only

Comment: sure u can @ Koushik

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in the below mentioned way :

Take a custom View in story board and set the auto layout

Use that view as titleView of navigation bar

**Code :**

```
//Here "NavigationView" is the name of view file (xib).
UIView *customVwNavigation = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NavigationView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

self.navigationItem.titleView = customVwNavigation;
```

**Screen shot of view with Autolayout :**

[image]

**Output :**

[image]

Hope it helps.