# Two Line Prompt - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Is there a way to make a two line prompt for a swift navigation bar? I currently cannot find a property to modify. The text I am currently displaying in the prompt comes from an external data model, so sometimes there is more text than fits on the screen. Thanks.

[Image Showing Text Outside of Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFp4g.png)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422383/uinavigationbar-multi-line-title

Comment: The `prompt` property of `UINavigationItem` only supports one line of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

**Swift 3.0**

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:350, height:50)) //width is subject to change, Defined as per your screen
label.backgroundColor =.clear
label.numberOfLines = 2
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.textColor = UIColor.white
label.text = "Your Text here"
self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

Comment: Why have you fixed the width of label as 350?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Yes, but width is subject to change, above one is just example which i have used.

Comment: The question is about the `prompt` property of `UINavigationItem`. This answer isn't really appropriate since there is already a title and also a prompt.

Comment: @rmaddy Is there any way to set the size of text in a prompt then? Thanks.

Comment: @MattP I don't think so. There is the `titleTextAttributes` property of `UINavigationBar` but I don't believe that affects the prompt, just the title.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation bar has a title and a prompt

```
navigationItem.title = "Title, large"
navigationItem.prompt = "One line prompt, small text, auto-shrink"
```

Having a prompt could be better that having a custom title view, because it gives you more height and it works great with searchbars. But make sure this is really what you want, since the code bellow is not tested on all devices iOS versions. This will just give you an idea how you can control almost anything regarding layout in the navigation bar

```
class MyNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
func allSubViews(views: [UIView]) {
    for view in views {
        if let label = view as? UILabel, label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth {
            if label.numberOfLines != 2 { //this is the promp label
                label.numberOfLines = 2
                let parent = label.superview
                parent?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: parent!.bounds.width, height: 44)

                parent!.removeConstraints(parent!.constraints)
                label.removeConstraints(label.constraints)
                label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent!.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
                label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent!.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
                label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent!.topAnchor).isActive = true
                label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent!.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }
            return
        }
        
        self.allSubViews(views: view.subviews)
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    allSubViews(views: self.subviews)
}
}
```

To use your navigation bar use:

```
let navVc = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: MyNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the prompt to be multi-line as shown in the image below. The trick is to search through all subviews of the UINavigationBar and somehow locate the prompt view. One way to do this is to first load the prompt with some well known text, then search the subviews for this well known text. In my example code I stored "Default Prompt" in the navigationItem.prompt before searching.

```
   func findPromptView( view: UIView )
   {
        for item in view.subviews {
            if let label = item as? UILabel {
                if let text = label.text {
                    print(text)
                    if (text == "Default Prompt") {
                        label.numberOfLines = 2
                        label.textAlignment = .center
                    }
                }
            }
            if item.subviews.count > 0 {
                findPromptView( view: item )
            }
        }
    }

    if let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navigationItem.prompt = "Default Prompt"
        findPromptView( view: navBar)
    }
```

[image]